# XML layout does not contain a root element

Tags: xml

I am trying to import below XML file.

```
<? xml version="1.0" ?>
<result>SUCCESS</result>
```

But it gives an error

```
XML layout does not contain a root element
```

Is there anything missing in this?

Comment: your parser is looking for a root element..to make it well formed just add an element that shall include the result element. <root> <result>SUCCESS</result></root>

Comment: What XML parser are you using?